# Set TFS wiki web editor git branch

Tags: git, team-foundation-server, wiki

I have a TFS 2015 and I would like to leverage the wiki functionality. However, it seem it commit only on the master git branch. As we use a Git-Flow model, I would prefer it to commit on the develop branch or maybe even a doc specific branch to preserve the model.

I have looked in the project parametters but I can't find anything related to the wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WiKi does not yet support branches but I spoke to the developer and they are working on it. No eta.

Comment: Do you have a source on a forum post or something ?